# Why Access ports should have the same trunk native vlan?

Tags: vlan, trunk, switchport

[image]

In the current switch Management VLAN is 48. Can you please someone explain it to me, why we dont give trunk native VLAN as 48, and we configure the same as access VLAN?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What brand of switch is this? Cisco?

Comment: @Jim Pap, could you explain why you would do so? There's simply no point.

Comment: It is not Cisco. It is an HP Switch.

Comment: @JFL because, i dont understand why is this happen. I am not the Network Admin. I didnt do that on my own.

Comment: Then you need to ask your network admin, we cannot guess why somebody else did a specific configuration. They could be many reasons, but we simply have no way to knowing why. Aslo network not under your control are off-topic here.

Comment: If i am guessing right. The access ports do not tag frames because en devices can handle them. So the frames are tagged before they got up to the trunk ports. So, with trunk native VLAN xxx, they tagged the frames with the specific native VLAN, in order to be handled from trunk ports?

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about netowkrs you do not directly control are off-topic here, as are speculation and guessing.

Answer (score 2):

Native vlan use for carrying all untagged network traffic and Device VLAN use to management purposes of devices.

But Management vlan is same as other User VLANs.

VLAN 1 is a by default Management VLAN(in cisco) and it must change to other vlan because of security reason. It is recommended by cisco.

In addition to that both management VLAN and native vlan should be separated from user VLANs.

> **Simply It is a best practice and we can use Management VLAN as a
>   Native vlan. But It is not a good practice.**

[Reference](https://learningnetwork.cisco.com/thread/64462)
[Reference 2](http://www.ciscopress.com/articles/article.asp?p=2181837&seqNum=11)